# Reading spaces with scanf

Tags: c, string, scanf, fgets

```
printf("Type first name:"); scanf("%[^\n]%*c",msg);
printf("Type last name: "); scanf("%[^\n]%*c",aux2);
....
printf("Type adress:"); scanf("%[^\n]%*c",aux2);
....
printf("Type phone:"); scanf("%[^\n]%*c",aux2);
```

I want to read some string with spaces.
But scanf here has no effect..
After running this,I get:"Type first name:Type last name:Type adress:Type phone:")
Also ,I use in my code scanf("%c",&c)` to read some chars...
 What's the problem here,why I can't read those string?

*edited

Comment: Please explain your problem

Comment: I'ts impossible to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Note: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",aux2);` does not read `"\n"`.

Comment: edited.sorry . . . . .  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not obvious what your problem is (to me, anyway), but if you want to read a line of text including spaces, `fgets` is probably the easiest solution.

```
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

Note that fgets will stop reading once it encounters the \n character but it will append it to your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a `\n` character (which probably came from previous inputs) is in the input stream(`stdin`) when execution of the program reaches the `scanf`s which you posted.

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",aux2);
```

will not scan `\n` if it is the next character in the `stdin` and fails.To fix it,just add a

```
getchar();
```

just before the first `scanf`. This will gobble up the trailing `\n` from the `stdin`.